# Deploying a self managed EKS cluster via Terraform

Tags: terraform, amazon-eks

It's my first time doing this, and this is mostly a copy pasted beginner example. Not sure what I'm missing.

```
  self_managed_node_group_defaults = {
    disk_size = 50
  }

  self_managed_node_groups = {
    bottlerocket = {
      name = "bottlerocket-self-mng"

      platform      = "bottlerocket"
      ami_id        = "xxx"
      instance_type = "t2.small"
      desired_size  = 2

      iam_role_additional_policies = ["arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonSSMManagedInstanceCore"]

      pre_bootstrap_user_data = <<-EOT
      echo "foo"
      export FOO=bar
      EOT

      bootstrap_extra_args = "--kubelet-extra-args '--node-labels=node.kubernetes.io/lifecycle=spot'"

      post_bootstrap_user_data = <<-EOT
      cd /tmp
      sudo yum install -y https://s3.amazonaws.com/ec2-downloads-windows/SSMAgent/latest/linux_amd64/amazon-ssm-agent.rpm
      sudo systemctl enable amazon-ssm-agent
      sudo systemctl start amazon-ssm-agent
      EOT
    }
  }
```

And the error it throws:

Error: Your query returned no results. Please change your search criteria and try again.
with module.eks.module.self_managed_node_group["bottlerocket"].data.aws_ami.eks_default[0]
on .terraform/modules/eks/modules/self-managed-node-group/main.tf line 5, in data "aws_ami" "eks_default":
data "aws_ami" "eks_default" {

Comment: Have you tried `terraform-aws-eks`, or does it not fit your use case?

Comment: This is terraform-aws-eks, but I only posted the self managed node snippet